.Net 8 React SPA error - TimeoutException: The create-react-app server did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 120 seconds
Getting this error when starting up the application for development,

Framework version: .Net 8.0.204
React typescript 18.2.0
Node 18.20.0
VS Version 17.9.6
Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions for configuring SPA.
Using following code to register SPA,
      builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
      {
          configuration.RootPath = "WebClient/dist";
      });
.....
    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "WebClient";
        // Only in local development use npm start. Not in test/production.
        if (environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
            spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "dev");
        }
    });

I have increased the timeout limit but still same error. We have the same set up in a .Net 6 app and it works fine but since .Net 8 there seems to be some changes in the proxy implementation which is causing this issue. I can see ReactDevelopmentServerMiddleware is executing the command and browse to front end from its url.
Tried debugging into the framework code but it didn't help much since I am not too familiar with what's going on.
Here is the full trace log view,
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      Starting create-react-app server on port 51062...
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      > paymentwebclient@0.0.0 dev

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      > vite

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      Port 5173 is in use, trying another one...

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
        VITE v5.1.6  ready in 1359 ms

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
        Γ₧£  Local:   http://localhost:5174/

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
        Γ₧£  Network: use --host to expose

dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[1]
      Hosting starting
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware[16]
      The WebRootPath was not found: ****\wwwroot. Static files may be unavailable.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7252
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5293
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: ***
dbug: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[2]
      Hosting started
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.TimeoutException: The create-react-app server did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 120 seconds. Check the log output for error information.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout[T](Task`1 task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, String message)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer.ReactDevelopmentServerMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<Attach>b__0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task`1 baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, Boolean proxy404s)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer>b__0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.TimeoutException: The create-react-app server did not start listening for requests within the timeout period of 120 seconds. Check the log output for error information.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout[T](Task`1 task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, String message)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer.ReactDevelopmentServerMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<Attach>b__0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task`1 baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, Boolean proxy404s)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer>b__0>d.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

